# Bootstrap 4 navbar height sass variable missing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have searched through the sass files of Bootstrap 4 and the $navbar-height is missing. What is the sass variable to change navbar height in Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 13):

I needed a sidebar with 100vh, but I was getting a vertical scrollbar because of the extra height from the navbar. This is what worked for me and the result looks perfect.

```
calc(100vh - #{$nav-link-height} - #{$nav-link-padding-y * 2})
```

From this I conclude that the sidebar's height is

```
$nav-link-height + $nav-link-padding-y * 2
```

Comment: This works like a charm, and sass compatible, must be chosen as valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

See this `$navbar-brand-height`.

Comment: What if navbar does not have a a brand?

Comment: It seems that there is no any variable for fixed height, its gets updated automatically based on their inner elements!

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution to be to manipulate the padding instead of the height, like so:

```
$navbar-brand-padding-y: 25px;
```